# Rewrite htaccess rule for a specific file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I have rewrite htaccess rule so that a specific file(terms.php) with extension goes without extension(terms) like below
xyz.com/terms.php --> xyz.com/terms

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/terms\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(terms)\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(terms)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```